# How create WaterDrop canvas?

Tags: android, svg, canvas, kotlin, android-canvas

I would like create a water drop using Canvas on Android.

I have a Path svg to help me build the Canva :

`M 250 550 C 300 650 500 650 550 550 C 600 500 600 400 550 300 C 500 200 450 200 400 100 C 350 200 300 200 250 300 C 200 400 200 500 250 550`

On Android, using the Path and Canvas Object, how can I draw this drop?

I calculated the ratio according to a height and a width and I managed to provide the following code. But the drop appears badly.

I think my path is not closed.

```
    // Starting point
    path.moveTo(5f* this.width / 16f, 11f * this.height / 16f)

    path.cubicTo(3f * this.width / 8f, 13f * this.height / 16,
                 5f * this.width / 8f, 13f * this.height / 16f,
                 11 * this.width / 16f, 11f * this.height / 16f)

    path.cubicTo(3f * this.width / 4f, 5f * this.height / 8f,
                 3f * this.width / 4f, this.height / 2f,
                 11f * this.width / 16f, 3f * this.height * 8f)

    path.cubicTo(5f * this.width / 8f, this.height / 4f,
                 9f * this.width / 16f, this.height / 4f,
                 this.width / 2f, this.height * 8f)

    path.cubicTo(7f * this.width / 16f, this.height / 4f,
                 3f * this.width / 8f, this.height / 4f,
                 5* this.width / 16f, 3f* this.height * 8f)

    path.cubicTo(this.width / 4f, this.height / 2f,
                 this.width / 4f, 5f* this.height / 8f,
                 5* this.width / 16f, 11f* this.height * 16f)

    canvas.drawPath(path, viewPaint)
```

Comment: Just stick the numbers in each M is a moveTo and each C is a cubicTo. Is that all you need?

Comment: Yes, it is all I need, I have update my post. With my code the drop not correctly displayed... I think my path is not closed.

Comment: 11f * this.height / 16f != 11f* this.height * 16f